# Casting void pointer to type specified by string

Tags: c++

Is there a way to cast a `void*` pointer to a type given by a string without a huge `if`-block?

Something like `parsePtr(void *ptr, String s) { return static_cast<s>(ptr); }` would be optimal.

I tried using a macro like`#define parsePtr(ptr, type) static_cast<type>(ptr)`, which works fine for *types* (like `int` or `float`) but not for strings.

`#define parsePtr(ptr, type) type == "int" ? static_cast<int*>(ptr) : static_cast<float*>(ptr)` also does not work for me.

I know one could do this:

```cpp
if (s == "int")
  return (int*)ptr;
else if (s == "float")
  return (float*)ptr;
else if (s == "char*")
  return (char**)ptr;
//....
```

but then my code would be long and hard to read.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Why do you need such a cast?

Comment: Why have a `void *` in the first place ?  You can only convert back to the original type (with a few exceptions) - so why throw the type information away in the first place.  Are you looking for `std::optional` or `std::variant` ?

Comment: Almost always when a C-style cast like that is use, it should be taken as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: It's impossible to make code like `parsePtr(void *ptr, String s) { return static_cast<s>(ptr); }` work. The target type of a cast needs to be known at compile time which certainly is not the case here, since different strings could be passed. Also the ite snippet makes little sense unless the return type of the function has different conversions from those types; if the return type is a pointer type though, there's just another implicit cast added to determine the return value, so why not cast directly.

Comment: Even if such a function existed, how would you declare its return type? `SOMETHING parsePtr(void* ptr, String s);`. The only pointer type that could represent all of the possible return types is `void*`, so the entire function just collapses to `void* parsePtr(void* ptr, String s) { return ptr; }` anyway.

Comment: @RichardCritten the type is returned by a library I use. I can get the type but then I have to cast it - like the library says in its examples. I could always put if-block but, like I said, this would inflate the code for no reason. Therefore I'm looking for a simple solution.

Comment: @Evg I can't work with the `void *` as I need to know the type at compile time.

Comment: "I need to know the type at compile time." But the string `s` doesn't arrive until runtime. If you know at compile time what the string `s` is going to be (say, because you have external knowledge not known to the compiler), then go ahead and cast it to what you know it is. C++ is a statically-typed language. You'll have to write a separate version for each possible type. (You're going to have to do this anyway, seeing as the code generation to use an `int` is different from the code generation to use a `char*`.)

Comment: `by a library I use` What library? Are you asking XY question?

Comment: "one could do this": No, not really. A function cannot return sometimes `int*`, sometimes `float*` and sometimes `char**`. You just can't do that. Not even with a huge block of `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

As several folks have already said in the comments, this isn't going to happen with a string. C++ is a statically-typed language, so such a runtime conversion is not possible.

However, C++ provides template metaprogramming for use cases like this.

```
template <typename T>
T* convert_pointer(void* ptr) {
  return static_cast<T*>(ptr);
}
```

Then you can call this function as

```
void* my_data = ...;
int* my_int = convert_pointer<int>(my_data);
```

But, again, this is of questionable utility. The better question is where these void pointers are coming from and how to make sure that the data is *actually* of the requisite type, and trusting the caller of your function to know the type of a `void*` without any validation is less than ideal.

Comment: This answer is very useful to me. In my case, I am forced to include a C library into a C++ compilation and use of void* within a callback was not a choice of mine. This workaround is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support what you are asking for. However, you can use a `std::(unordered_)map` instead of a series of `if`s, at least, eg:

```cpp
using vptr_t = std::variant<int*, float*, char**, etc>;
using convert_func_t = vptr_t (*)(void*);

template <typename T>
vptr_t convert_func(void* ptr) {
  return static_cast<T*>(ptr);
}

vptr_t parsePtr(void *ptr, const std::string &type)
{
    static const std::unordered_map<std::string, convert_func_t> cvt = {
        {"int", &convert_func<int>},
        {"float", &convert_func<float>},
        {"char*", &convert_func<char*>},
        //...
    };
    return cvt.at(type)(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to cast a void Pointer to a type given by a String without a huge if-block?

No, there is no such way. C++ programming language is a statically-typed programming language, which means that every type has to be typed out and handled separately in the source file before compiling the program.

Comment: Weeelll, what about it?